# Mount host directory into a docker container run from within docker container

Tags: docker

I have some unusual case. Namely, I run a docker container, let us call it `container1` and I mount docker socket from my host into it: `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.

Then, from within a `container1` I want to run another container, let us call it `container2`. As I have a host's docker socket mounted, I can do that with ease.

Now the question: how can I mount a directory from my host inside `container2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mounted the docker socket, what you do wiht `docker` in `container1` is just like what you do on the host. If you need to mount a directory from host to `container2`, just use `-v /path/on/host:/target`. Because it's the `docker` running on the host, that's going to interpret `/path/on/host`

Comment: OMG. I have spent a couple of hours totally confusing what a host is... Sorry.

Comment: Critically, the `docker run -v` option or API equivalent _always_ takes physical-host paths: you cannot bind-mount a directory from container1 into container2.